# some times the hardest part is knowing what word to google?

Tags: list, dashboard

I have several tables, each one of them has a pending column. I was wondering what its called if made another table that would fill with all of the items from the given tables with any item that was pending? That way my boss would only have one spot he would have to check to approve anything.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a lookup column? This will allow you to get data from another location into the current list.

Comment: I thought of that. the only problem is that I am pulling information from different lists and in each list I am pulling different information types. so I don't think that will work for me but, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It's SharePoint so they are referred to as lists, not tables. (not trying to be pedantic, but if you're googling, then this is an important distinction.)

While we could make copies of all list items from a bunch of different lists and put those copies in a master list, this tends to be difficult and unwieldy (what happens if a list item is updated, for example, the master list would have to be updated as well).

Instead, use a query. The exact specifics will depend on what version of SP you're running, and where the lists are stored. If the lists are all in one site collection, then you can use the content query web part (google: "CQWP"). The cqwp is designed for this purpose: in one spot, display list items from several different lists.

If you're in SP 2013 Enterprise, you can use the content search part. This web part is in some ways similar to the CQWP, though it can display items from different site collections.

(If you can go to a "view contents" page and see all the lists, then they're all in the same site. Understanding site collections is a bit trickier)